# Htaccess how to remove trailing slash from file but not directory

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache2

My website is coded using PHP. In my htaccess file I am using the following to remove the php file extension from my urls:

```
 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
 RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
 RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1.php [L]
```

*example: www.mysite.com/folder/file.php will be directed to www.mysite.com/folder/file*

If I navigate to a directory without adding a trailing slash the server automatically adds one:

*example: www.mysite.com/folder will be directed to www.mysite.com/folder/*

If I navigate to a file instead and add a trailing slash I get an internal server error

Is there code I can add to my htaccess file where the server can determine if the url is to a file instead of a folder? And instead of throwing an error, remove the trailing slash so that the file will be shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert this rule at top of your .htaccess to remove trailing slash for non-directories:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)/+$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,NE,L]
```